# How to display categories order by parent?

Tags: django, django-models

I have model:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'categories'
        ordering = ['parent']
```

but in admin i get:

```
Infinite loop caused by ordering.
```

How to display categories with parent ordering?

I want to sort categories like this:

```
category 1
children of category 1
children of category 1
children of category 1 (category 1a)
children of category 1a
children of category 1
category 2
children of category 2
children of category 2
... etc
```

Comment: Change `ordering = ['parent']` to `ordering = ['parent__id']`

Comment: Ok, thats works but I want to sort by parent: parent(children,children),next parent(children_parent(children), children) etc...

Comment: Could you explain the ordering that you want to achieve more precisely?